# Як правильно: гіроскутер чи героскутер?

Tags: вибір-слова, іменники, запозичені-слова

Багато різних посилань можна побачити щодо обидвох варіантів слова, однак здебільшого в оголошенням про купівлю або у блогах. Для прикладу наведу:

- Гіроскутер [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELWyZ7RFvJs), [2](https://gtf-drive.com/ua-ua/news/about-hoverboard).
- Героскутер [1](https://www.olx.ua/uk/obyavlenie/prodam-geroskuter-ne-dorogo-IDBntz2.html#aaebf510b0), [2](https://speshka.com/sp/item-17010715/).

Оскільки це слово недавно з’явилося на наших теренах,  то [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghiroskuter) його не подає.

Answer (score 4):

Правильний варіант ***ГІРОСКУТЕР***, адже слово перекладене з англ. *GyroScooter*, що в свою чергу утворене від злиття двох слів - *gyro* i *scooter*

Англійсько-українські словники

> **[gyro](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=gyro&dicts=all&highlight=on)**  гіроско́п, дзи́ґа || гіроско́пний, дзи́ґовий
>
> **[scooter](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=scooter%20&dicts=all&highlight=on)** 3) ску́тер

Answer (score 2):

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) знаходимо:

> **Гіроскутер** (двоколісний скутер).

На підтвердження цього знаходимо у [Словнику іншомовних слів Мельничука](http://slovopedia.org.ua/42/53395/280395.html):

> **ГІРО**... 
>   (від грец. γϋρος – коло, γυρεύω – обертаюсь) 
>   у складних словах відповідає поняттю «обертовий рух».

Варіант **гЕроскутер** зустрічається набагато менше на просторах інтернету і є неправильним на позначення даного виду транспорту.